# Non-Static Methods Being Called Statically PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, static-methods, non-static

I am new to PHP, and have encountered many problems with some code that I am writing that I have been able to solve. But, one problem seems to never disappear. I constantly receive the error message `Fatal error: Non-static method mysqli::select_db() cannot be called statically`. The code the error refers to will be below. If anyone has a solution to this problem, as well as an explanation, that would be most helpful.

```
$db_selected = mysqli::select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
```

EDIT

Other Stack Exchange questions are not helpful for this situation. Explaining to me the fact my question is low-level does not help, as I already understand that and acknowledged it above.

Comment: The error message is as clear as it can be. You call a non static method (a function inside an object) in a static manner (so without an object). That does not work.

Comment: Did you even _think_ about taking a single look at the documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php Not only that it explains all details, it also shows clear and easy examples. What else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
```

You're trying to call a function that's not avaiable, you have to choose a DB like above.

Edit:
But i recommend just selected the DB when you're instantiating the connection like this:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USEER', 'PASS', 'DB');
```

Comment: This would be procedural style. It looks like the OP does not want that. He looks for OOP style.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, it's a really stupid question and I appreciate someone actually answering the question instead of commenting about said stupidity... :)

Comment: @SamK Not knowing how something works and asking is fine. no question is stupid. But not reading the documentation when you have an issue is something that you should think about...

Comment: @arkascha I have looked at documentation, but it was somewhat confusing, and I still need time to get used to it.

Comment: All fine. So now you got the basic idea? First create the object, then use it.